# Where does Server Audit store my file size radio button choice?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a Server Audit definition and I can locate the value I set for Max File Size in `sys.server_file_audits`.  But I cannot find a column that represents the value I selected for the radio button (MB, GB, TB). Where does the system store this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The value is stored in MB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280544.aspx).

So if you picked 10 MB it would store 10. If you picked 10 GB it would store 10240 (10 * 1024). Etc. It doesn't store your radio button choice separately (after all, if you used DDL instead of the GUI, you didn't use a radio button in the first place).

You'll also notice that if you choose 1024 GB, hit OK, then open the properties dialog again, it doesn't remember your choice - it shows 1048576 MB (1024 * 1024).

Comment: Thanks, Aaron, for your answer and your explanation.  That clears it up.